# Can Spring Data JPA Enforce ManyToOne Relationship via @JoinColumn

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot application using Spring Data REST and Spring Data JPA. I have two domain entities: Student and Classroom, where many students can belong to the same classroom.

Student:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Integer studentId;  // This Id has been setup as auto generated in DB

    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    private Integer roomId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Classroom classroom;
   }
```

Classroom:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASSROOM")
public class Classroom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    private Integer roomId;  // This Id has been setup as auto generated in DB

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classroom")
    private List<Student> studentList;

    .....// other fields related to a classroom
  }
```

And the Student repository:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student , Integer>{
  List<Student> findByClassroom(@Param("room") Classroom room);
}
```

And the Classroom repository:

```
public interface ClassroomRepository extends CrudRepository<Classroom , Integer>{
}
```

And I have a SpringApplication main file, but no controller.

There is already one classroom with room id=1 in the CLASSROOM table. When I gave the following request to POST to http://localhost:8080/students, a new student record was created in the Student table, which I expected it to fail because there isn't a classroom with id=100 exists in the CLASSROOM.

So my question is that: can Spring Data JPA enforce a manyToOne relationship or this foreign key enforcement has to be done on the database side (**the not-null ROOM_ID column in the Student table is NOT defined as foreign key** by our DBA for a legitimate consideration).  If it has to be done on the database side, what is the point to define the manyToOne relationship in entity files?

Also, I know that I have redundant classroom fields in the Student entity, I just don't know which one to keep in the Student entity (the roomId or the "classroom" field), because when I create a student, I want to give only the roomId of a classroom in the request.  Thanks!

```
{ 
  "roomId": 100  // I expect this request to fail because no roomId=100 in the CLASSROOM table.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what is the point to define the manyToOne relationship in entity files

Because is an Object Relational Mapping tool that allows you define entity graphs.

You are currently passing `roomId` which in your Entity is just another field so you needs to remove that.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Integer studentId;  // This Id has been setup as auto generated in DB

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID", nullable = false)
    private Classroom classroom;
}
```

In Spring Data Rest you then defined an association by passing the self link of the referenced entity.

Your request then needs to look like the below:

```
{ 
  "classroom" : "http://localhost:8080/classrooms/1"
}
```

Also removing the ID as you are POSTing a new record and, as you note, the ID is auto-generated in the database.

See also:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Comment: Thank you.  I removed "roomId" from the Student entity and I also updated the Student repository (in the above post too).  However, when I gave the request in your answer in postman, I am getting an error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ROOM_ID', table 'STUDENT'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".  How do I give the roomId value thru the request?

Comment: If `http://localhost:8080/classrooms/1` returns a classroom and you have removed `updatable = false, insertable = false` from the join column definition then it should work.